# Inotifywait not working on folders mounted via fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, inotify

I'm trying to watch a folder via inotifywait which is mounted via fstab and originally located on an extern NAS. Inotifywait is reacting on any change done by SFTP-Connection or directly via terminal, but when I'm adding a file from 'NAS-side' it is not recognized. Does anyone know about this issue?

Mounting is done via etc/fstab:

```
//fritz.box/FRITZ.NAS/FRITZ/faxbox      /home/pi/shares/fb-faxbox       cifs    vers=1.0,nofail,credentials=/home/pi/.smbcredentials,uid=pi,gid=pi      0       0
```

Inotify-Script faxwatch.sh (located in /home/pi):

```
#!/bin/sh 
inotifywait -m /home/pi/shares/fb-faxbox |
  while read path action file; do
    echo "'$file' in directory '$path' via '$action' recognized."
  done
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: related: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/monitoring-file-changes-with-linux-over-the-network/